# setting value of an input with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, frontend

I'm trying to set the value of a dropdown list based on another dropdown list value inside Angular and using jQuery, it works and it auto selects the wanted value but it doesn't add the value to the database after submitting. I'm sure everything is fine concerning the database connection because choosing any other selected value (for example euro in this case) is added to database.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#country").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "usa") {
      $("#currency").val("dollar");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="usa">usa</option>
  <option value="france">france</option>
</select>

<select id="currency" name="currency">
  <option value="dollar">dollar</option>
  <option value="euro">euro</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>

</form>
```

***NB: Dollar becomes selected but when submitting it's not added to database, whereas if I remove the jQuery function and choose manually the currency , it adds to the database and everything is fine .***

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I suspect the issue lies elsewhere... probably your submit handler.

Comment: Your issue is most likely related to using jQuery in an angular app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery code seems to be good... but my question is, why are you using jQuery to update a form in Angular.

Did you evaluate use tempalte-driven or reactive forms instead? Below you can find your form written as template driven.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <select id="country" name="country" (change)="onCountryChange()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
      <option
        *ngFor="let country of countries"
        [value]="country">
        {{ country }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <select id="currency" name="currency" [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency">
      <option
        *ngFor="let currency of currencies"
        [value]="currency">
        {{ currency }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>

</form>
```

And in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BR5NftJXxiiD6203) you can find the full example using template-driven form... but if I where you, I would go for the reactive form approach.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't want to link france to euro I just want to link usa to dollar and when choosing france i want to choose euro manually , can you update the code for this purpose please ? thank you

Comment: okay, in that case, you can see this other plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/y54kebLYn05gqYvA ). I made some changes and I created a linkedCurrencies variable if you want to link more countries and currencies in the future. Also, if you uncomment the commented code, USA will be the option by default.